# Can TSQL convert from boolean to BIT

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I was creating a function that returns BIT, I tried to "Return @count < 1", that did not work, how to convert boolean to BIT in TSQL.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You will need to have a conditional statement:

```
if @count < 1
    return 1
else
    return 0
```

Or you could use a `CASE` statement:

```
case
    when @count < 1 then return 1
    else return 0
end
```

Comment: `CASE` is an expression, not a statement.  As such you can't tuck a `RETURN` statement inside a `CASE`.  Your second example won't parse.

Answer (score 3):

Can count ever be negative? And count should be integer

So what you want is "1 if @COUNT = zero, zero otherwise"

```
RETURN 1 - SIGN(@COUNT)
```

Comment: FYI From documentation here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/bit-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017&viewFallbackFrom=sql-server-2014 "Converting to bit promotes any nonzero value to 1."

Answer (score 1):

Or a simple transmogrification of Shark's answer:

```
return case
    when @Count < 1 then 1
    else 0
    end
```

Note that a CASE may have as many WHEN clauses as you need.

Trivia: Curiously, a BIT can be set to 'TRUE' or 'FALSE'.  Yeah, quoted strings.  Go figure.